# Upload file to google drive with access_token java

Tags: java, post, google-drive-api, access-token, google-api-java-client

I have website with java server-side.

When user submit a form, I want the application to take the text from the inputs in the form, and upload it as a .txt file to *my* google drive account.

**What I can do so far:**

1. I'm able to take the text from the client to the server-side.
2. I'm able to create a file from text.
3. I'm able to get an access_token using refresh token.

***What I can NOT do:***

I'm not able to take the file and upload it to my google drive using the valid access_token because I don't know how to do the post request.

What I have tried with no luck:

```
            File file = new File ("omer.txt");

            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media");

            //add reuqest header
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
            //execute the post request and upload the file to my google drive using the access token
            //execute the post request and upload the file to my google drive using the access token
```

Here I tried to upload a txt file, I tried it but did not know what to put in the post parameters.

So : How can I upload my txt file to my google drive using my valid access_token?

Comment: Where are you getting the access token?  If you are using the Google api java client as you have tagged your question why arent you using it for the [upload](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-upload)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've a refresh token from the oauth playground. Now I'm using it to get access_token every post request. I will not use it because it is from media upload, and I need a .txt file upload.(not resumable upload).

Comment: You realize that that refresh token is only going to work for about two hours right then its going to expire?  Why arent you using a service account and sharing your drive account with that so it can upload your data to your account?  I am not sure i understand why you doint want to use the method Google has given you for uploading all file types.   A text file and a Jpeg have no difference in the upload method other then the content type

Comment: The refresh token wont expire. You are talking about the access_token that is valid for one hours only. Refresh token can stay for few months, and then expire. I don't want to share my drive, I want to use a simple post request to upload my file.

Comment: oauth playground is not the place for you to be creating Access tokens or refresh tokens for use in production.  You should be using your own code to create your own access token and refresh tokens.  oauth playground is a developer **TESTING** tool only.

Comment: I'm new to the drive api and the google api.
Please can you tell me how could I use the access token to upload the file ? Or check it if you are an expert?

Comment: 1. you have the wrong content type for .txt.  2. you are not setting the size of the upload 3. you are not actually uploading any data.   Since you want to do it manually rather than use the library this documentation may help https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload

Comment: I know dude. That is my question. How do I actually put the data of my file in the post request? I saw the link you gave, and could not understand how to put my file data.

Comment: And what is the correct type for .txt file ?

Comment: Google is your friend Try mime type for .txt

Comment: Thank you. And can you please help me with the post request? How can I put the .txt file data inside it ? I searched google a lot and could not found. And I have edited my question to .txt file.